# How to show list of images in grid view builder if list is not empty

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart, gridview

i have a list which contains list of images, i want to show these in my grid view builder if list if not empty other wise i just want to show static + symbol in my grid view builder.

it is my list

```
var otherPersonOfferList = <Inventory>[].obs;
```

and this is my grid view builder which i have extracted as a widget and using it in my screen

```
import 'package:bartermade/models/Get_Inventory.dart';
import 'package:bartermade/models/inventory.dart';
import 'package:bartermade/widgets/inventoryTile.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../controllers/inventoryController.dart';

class OfferGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  OfferGrid(
      {Key? key,
      required this.list,
      required this.modelSheetHeading,
      required this.gestureState})
      : super(key: key);
  String modelSheetHeading;
  List<Inventory> list;
  bool gestureState;

  @override
  State<OfferGrid> createState() => _OfferGridState();
}

class _OfferGridState extends State<OfferGrid> {
  InventoryController inventoryController = Get.find();
  bool isDeleting = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.gestureState == true
        ? (inventoryController.otherPersonOfferList == [] ||
            inventoryController.otherPersonOfferList.length == 0 ||
            inventoryController.otherPersonOfferList.isEmpty)
        : (inventoryController.myOfferList == [] ||
            inventoryController.myOfferList.length == 0 ||
            inventoryController.myOfferList.isEmpty)) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return InventoryTile(
                      modelSheetHeading: widget.modelSheetHeading,
                      list: widget.gestureState == true
                          ? inventoryController.traderInventoryList
                          : inventoryController.myInventoryList1,
                      inventoryController: inventoryController,
                      gestureState: widget.gestureState);
                });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 90,
            width: 90,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 35,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: widget.list.length + 1,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == widget.list.length) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return InventoryTile(
                              modelSheetHeading: widget.modelSheetHeading,
                              list: widget.gestureState == true
                                  ? inventoryController.traderInventoryList
                                  : inventoryController.myInventoryList1,
                              inventoryController: inventoryController,
                              gestureState: widget.gestureState);
                        });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onLongPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isDeleting = true;
                        });
                      },
                      onTap : (){
                        setState(() {
                          isDeleting = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        height: 100,
                        width: 200,
                        imageUrl: //  "https://asia-exstatic-vivofs.vivo.com/PSee2l50xoirPK7y/1642733614422/0ae79529ef33f2b3eb7602f89c1472b3.jpg"
                            "${widget.list[index].url}",
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  isDeleting == true
                      ? Positioned(
                          right: 0,
                          top: 0,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            radius: 10,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.remove,
                              size: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : SizedBox()
                ],
              );
            }
          });
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my screen where is just want to check if my list is non empty then fill my grid view with images otherwise just show + sign in grid view

```
import 'package:bartermade/controllers/inventoryController.dart';
import 'package:bartermade/models/Get_Inventory.dart';
import 'package:bartermade/models/inventory.dart';
import 'package:bartermade/screens/chat/chatScreen.dart';
import 'package:bartermade/utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:bartermade/widgets/snackBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../../services/inventoryService.dart';
import '../../../../widgets/offerGrid.dart';

class OfferTradeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   String postUserId;
   String postUserName;
  OfferTradeScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.postUserId,
    required this.postUserName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OfferTradeScreen> createState() => _OfferTradeScreenState();
}

class _OfferTradeScreenState extends State<OfferTradeScreen> {
  // TradeController tradeController = Get.put(TradeController());
  InventoryController inventoryController = Get.put(InventoryController());
  // GiftStorageService giftStorageService = GiftStorageService();
  // GiftController giftController = Get.put(GiftController());
  // ProfileController profileController = Get.put(ProfileController());
  // TradeStorageService tradeStorageService = TradeStorageService();
  // TradingService tradingService = TradingService();
  // PreferenceService preferenceService = PreferenceService();
  late List<Inventory> otherPersonList;
  late List<Inventory> myList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    inventoryController.getOtherUserInventory(widget.postUserId);
    otherPersonList = inventoryController.otherPersonOfferList;
    myList = inventoryController.myOfferList;
  }

  otherPersonlistener() {
    inventoryController.otherPersonOfferList.listen((p0) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          otherPersonList = p0;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  mylistener() {
    inventoryController.myOfferList.listen((p0) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          myList = p0;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  int draggableIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("-------building------");
    otherPersonlistener();
    mylistener();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleSpacing: 0,
        leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              inventoryController.myOfferList.clear();
              inventoryController.otherPersonOfferList.clear();
              Get.back();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
        title: Text(
          "Offer",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.to(() => ChatScreen(
                      currentUserId: widget.postUserId,
                      recieverId: inventoryController.userId.toString()));
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.message)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 10,
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        "${widget.postUserName} Inventory",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ),
                    OfferGrid(
                      gestureState: true,
                      list: otherPersonList,
                      modelSheetHeading: "${widget.postUserName}",
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 2,
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 3,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 10,
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "My Inventory",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    OfferGrid(
                      gestureState: false,
                      list: myList,
                      modelSheetHeading: "My Inventory",
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(child: Obx(() {
              return inventoryController.makingOffer.value == true
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: AppColors.pinkAppBar,
                    )
                  : ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (inventoryController.otherPersonOfferList.isEmpty &&
                            inventoryController.myOfferList.isEmpty) {
                          showSnackBar(
                              "Please add both inventories to make offer",
                              context);
                        } else {
                          inventoryController.postOffer(
                              widget.postUserId, context);
                        }
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10, horizontal: 50)),
                      child: Text("Send Offer"));
            }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User following code :

```
  GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data.length,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 17,
              mainAxisSpacing: 17,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (
              context,
              index,
            ) {
              return Obx(
                () => InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                   
                  },
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: ColorConfig.colorDarkBlue, width: 2),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(ImagePath.unselectedContainer), ///imageURL
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          )),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(data[index].heading,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: ThemeConstants.textThemeFontSize18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                color: ColorConfig.colorDarkBlue)),
                      ),
                      height: 150,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```